# Нужен совет по хранению фотографий для сайта обьявлений

Tags: php

Есть небольшой проект - сайт с объявлениями, где есть объявление и фотографии к нему.
Я расскажу как сделал обработку и хранение фотографий, а Вы подскажите как можно сделать лучше и правильно.

1. Пользователь загружает через форму фотографии. (одну или несколько).
2. Отправляем фотографии на сервер.
3. if (is_uploaded_file - переименуем их и перенесем их во временную папку /temp
   (зачем спросите Вы, так как они и так во временной папке, отвечу, что пользователь может догружать фотографии, а фотографии хранятся во временной папке $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] до момента закрытия скрипта)
4. Помещая во временную папку, я сохраняю имя созданного файла в сессии (в под массиве $_SESSION['photo'])
5. Там же и сразу же создаю превью загруженной фото и даю ей имя _prev.jpeg, и так же записываю имя этой превью в массив $_SESSION['photoprev']
6. Далее когда пользователь заполнит все строки объявления и нажмет сохранить, в обработчике формы на сервере обрабатываются поля input, и записываются в базу, где получаем новый id объявления
7. получив id объявления, записываем фотографии в таблицу photo из массива сессии, присваивая каждой фотографии id объявления (что бы потом достать их по id объявлению).
8. Файлы c префиксом _prev не записываются в базу, а просто добавляются к имени нужной фотографии при выводе (когда в базе запрашивается список фото к объявлению). То есть в папке фотографий лежит и фото и превью фото (с префиксом _prev), но в базе записано только имя основного, большого фото.

Теперь почему сессия для хранения массива фото перед записью.
Один из вариантов был создавать id объявления до сохранения и все загруженные файлы присваивать сразу нужному объявлению, но так как процент не завершённых (не оформленных) объявлений высок, я пошёл по пути экономии места на сервере и не хранить фотографии неоформленных объявлений.

По-этому фотографии пока сессия открыта, сохраняются во временной папке, а потом если оформлено объявление - переносится в основную папку, а имена фотографий сохраняются в базе и привязываются к объявлению. А если объявление не сохранено - то удаляются фотографии из временной папки. Как собственно несохраненное объявление.

1. Подскажите, что думаете на счёт алгоритма обработки и какие есть мысли по улучшению?
2. Как лучше работать с превьюшками. Вот сгенерировал её после загрузки. А дальше что с ней делать? Нужно ли их имена сохранять в базу? (например завести в таблице фото ключ который бы указывал что фотка с id 354, привязана к фотке id 125). Имеет ли в этом смысл? Или достаточно знать перфикс превью и просто генерировать имя превью на основе имя файла фото.

Заранее спасибо за любые мысли и советы. Очень нужно мне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше сразу создавать запись в базе. Прикреплять к ней фотографии и другие данные.

Я могу добавлять объявление и у меня пропадет подключение. Я зайду только через 2 дня и моя сессия пропадет. И заново все вводить и грузить?

Для экономии места не сервере объявления и все их файлы можно удалять по крону через неделю или две. (для определения какие удалять можно завести поле статус)

Имена сохранять в базу ненужно это доп уязвимость. Генерируйте их сами.
Превью в базу можно не сохранять, а только файл с префиксом делать.

Comment: вообщем как сделать идеально - я так и не понял :) Но в любом случае спасибо за коммент.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать сессию для временного хранения файлов не стоит. Пользователь выбирает файлы и они сразу не летят на сервер. Только после нажатия кнопки submit будет произведена отправка файлов на сервер вам просто стоит указать условие перед отправкой запроса и POSTFILE на корректность заполнение формы. Хранить лучше пути к файлу в базе данных. Как вы и писали выше чтобы у каждого файла был свой id и указатель id объявления к которому принадлежит сам файл.
Как вариант сделайте кнопку отправки формы неактивной с помощью JS и только при верном заполнении всех полей кнопка станет активна. 
Превьюшки мне кажется вовсе не нужны. Просто создайте css  стиль назовите его prev задайте параметр стилю 100px - 100px  и у вас основная картинка будет превьюшкой там где вы у картинки укажете этот стиль.

Comment: Превьюшки нужны. В наше время особенно. Если вы грузите страничку с 10ю объявлениями и там 10 картинок по 2 мегабайта? И вы еще с сотового телефона по 3G?

Comment: Так картинки все должны обрабатываться при загрузке и после обработки они весят по 250 кб. примерно. Зачем вам хранить картинки на сервере в оригинале ?

Comment: Чтобы я мог рассмотреть товар поближе =)

Comment: Ну если у вас аукцион художественных картин то да нужно качество на максимум. А остальное все обрабатывается.

Comment: У всех товаром должна быть фото большое оно может быть ограничено по размеру, но не превью.